# How to access HMAcessory to my sample application using matterNodeId?

Tags: swift, homekit

I have commissioned a matter accessory (ERF32) into the Homekit app, using an Apple controller (Homepod mini.)
I am able to read the accessory using Homekit APIs

```
for accessory in home.accessories.filter({ $0.matterNodeID != nil }) {
   print(accessory.matterNodeID)
}
```

I can access matterNodeID Using Homekit API’s, but I do not understand how we can see clusters in the HMAccessory.

Does homekit API support read the clusters from HomeKit commissioned matter accessories? I am not seeing any documentation on Homekit.

Does anyone implemented this use case, if so could you please provide a sample code for this?

I have tried with matter SDK to convert HMAccessory to Matter accessory, i am unable to achive this.